# How to add the result of javascript prompt, to a form's inputs

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a form that manages a list.

Only the supervisor should be allowed to delete items from the list.

In order to do this I have the following code (this is created by php for each item in the list) :

```
<form id ="delete_item" name="delete_item" method="post" action="delete_item.php"
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" id="item_id" value="12345678">
    <input type="image" alt="submit" src=".\images\delete.png" id="item_delete_execute" name="item_delete_execute">
</form>
```

the javascript file for this form contains the following:

```
$(document).ready(set_up_listeners);
function set_up_listeners() {
    $("#delete_item").submit(confirm_delete);
}

function confirm_delete() {
    var pass;
    pass = prompt("in order to delete this item, please enter your password", "");
    (code here to verify password, using ajax to execute a php script that checks against the database)
    return (true if the password checks out, so it can continue with the post, otherwise false);

}
```

is there a way to add the value that the variable pass has, so that the delete_item.php script can see it in one of its $_POST variables?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: You are using prompt for entering a password? Problem here is the fact you want to make an Ajax call in a situation where you need an synchronous request.

Comment: yes, I thought I should ask for the password just to make sure that the user didn't click on the delete button by accident, and right now I have validation through ajax after the password is given, but I would rather transfer that validation to my delete_item.php script

Comment: data is just a string and will be obtained before making the ajax call. You can use $.post({url: 'delete_item.php', data: {....password: pass}})

Comment: oh so you mean, instead of adding the data to the original form and then doing a submit, my confirm_delete() function should create an ajax call to the php script and append the form's data along with the password?

yeah that could work, thank you